# Can't install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 19.10 after Kernel update

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, kernel

Process:

```bsh
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

That fails with

```
Setting up nvidia-dkms-440 (440.59-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-440.59 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-40-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.3.0-40-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-440.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.59/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-440 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-440 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
```

Ok, let's check out `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.59/build/make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-440.59 for kernel 5.3.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Mon 17 Feb 2020 12:33:02 PM CST
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.59/build need-modorder=1
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
```

`make oldconfig && make prepare` fails with:

Wait a second... It's throwing `clang` errors under that? See below:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo update-alternatives --all`

Change everything with `clang` selected back to `gcc`

It works. Finally.

Comment: Unbelievable. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything with clang or gcc in that menu. Looks like this. https://i.postimg.cc/6Q8dzH71/update-alternatives.png

Comment: @Deleet There's multiple options in `update-alternatives`, just press `ENTER` to leve the non-compiler ones as they are.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd changed 2 out of the 3 gcc/clang references before but missed the 3rd. Setting that as well and reinstalling the drivers finally made it work.

Comment: Glad I could help! It's a really weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rolling back to the default Kernel (for me, was 5.0.0-32-generic). On this, had no problems installing the Nvidia drivers. Beware that you need to uninstall the later kernels, not merely run an older one. The Nvidia installer will try to use the newest kernel you have installed, not the one you are running, so you have to uninstall the newer ones.

It may work with other newer kernels below 5.7.4 that I originally tried with. I tried with 5.4.48 (the latest of the LTS kernel) but this gave an unusual green screen of death when booting.

[image]

Comment: This issue's been plaguing me for at least the last 6 years, long before kernel 5.0.0. It could be that things don't have to be rebuilt on the default kernel or you could simply have a different issue.

Comment: Did you check the log it directed you to?

Comment: Yes, it goes to this bug (in OP). It's a kernel driver incompatibility problem.